# Grill html and CSS

Tags: html

I wanted to know how I could create a grill for my website, I wanted this to be like a 3*7 table with equal sizes, as you can see in the picture and that I could replace the spaces with an image in the future. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to use a `<table>` tag.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: [HTML Div Table Generator | DIV TABLE.COM](https://divtable.com/generator/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: grid` property

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto; 
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
```

here i have put width of Columns and Rows to auto you can put it according to your need also go ahead and read about

[CSS Display Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using `<table>` tag :

```html
<table style="width: 50%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```